# Trying to Fire a ASP.NET Custom Control Button Event

Tags: asp.net, events, controls

I have a simple test custom control that I have created and am trying to figure out why the click event will not fire. below is the code. I simply create an instance of the control on a test page with

Page_Load of .aspx page that consumes the control
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.Form.Controls.Add(new TestControl()); 
        }

The page does a post back but it does not pick up the click event in the user control. Please explain what I am doing incorrectly or a better way to approach this with a specific pattern etc.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WorldOfTest
{
```

public class TestControl : WebControl
    {
        private Button btn;

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {            
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    protected override void EnsureChildControls()
    {
        btn = new Button();           
        this.Controls.Add(btn); 
        base.EnsureChildControls();
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {

        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);  
        btn.Text = "test button";                         
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        btn.RenderControl(writer); ;
    }

}
}
```

Thank You for your help

Comment: When in the forms's lifecycle are you adding the control to the collection?

Comment: when I add the control to the form I am adding it in the PageLoad, I also tried the PreRender but that did not solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried 1) adding it earlier in the lifecycle 2) giving it an ID?

Comment: Jason, I have tried adding it earlier in the life cycle, with an ID without an ID. I am at a loss right now on how the same code can work for BalaR and not on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add your `btn` to `Controls` collection like this

```
    protected override void EnsureChildControls()
    {
        this.btn = new Button();   
        Controls.Add(btn);         
        base.EnsureChildControls();
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Seems to be working fine for me once I add the button to the control's collection.

I tried this

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Form.Controls.Add(new Tester());
    }
```

and I get this
[image]

Comment: I added it to the collection in EnsureChildControls. The event is still not firing.

Comment: I have to be missing something, I did exactly what you did and the behavior still acts like a page refresh.       I added my new code based on your suggestions in the original comment. Can you post your control code?

Comment: For the control, I have exactly what you have in your question plus the one line from from my answer to add btn to Controls collection.

Comment: still a no go. Are there any setting in the webconfig that I may be missing?

Comment: Bala R. Thanks for your help with this, I finally got it to wire up and work as expected.

Comment: @TampaRich, Hi Tamp, could you post your solution? I'm having the exact problem. The button instance is hold by page, but it's click event cannot be fired.